# Javascript package management with bower and grunt

Tags: gruntjs, concatenation, bower, uglifyjs

So in my project my javascript comprises of

- Third party libraries (jquery, bootstrap, jquery plugins etc)
- Custom libraries
- Code embedded inline in the html in view files between `<script>$(function(){});</script>`

Pretty standard stuff.

My goal was to find a reliable, automated way, to minify all my separate javascript files (approx 25 files) into one file for production.

I've installed `bower` and it seems like a good way to keep my external libraries up to date. I've also installed `grunt`. I'm using a bower plugin in grunt that copies all downloaded files to a specified directory, then `concat` can look in that directory to combine them and finally `uglifyJS` minifies the file. Again, it seems like a standard setup of grunt.

The bower plugin will create a folder like

```
vendorjs

 - bootstrap.js
 - jquery.js
 - etc
```

`concat` will then read from this dir, and as the files are in alphabetical order will combine them in an incorrect order, bootstrap before jquery, so it wont be of use.

I'm aware of RequireJS, but it seems like overkill for my needs. And it also seems like I'd need to rewrite all of my js to comply with the requirements of RequireJS.

Is there some configuration I'm missing that will help with my problem? Am I going about this in the wrong way?

---

**Edit** this is my Gruntfile.js for more clarity.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    bower: {
        dev: {
            dest: 'vendorjs',
            options: {
                stripJsAffix: true
            }
        }
    }
    concat: {
        options: {
            separator: ';'
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['vendorjs/*.js'],
            dest: 'vendor.js'
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                '../../public/js/admin/vendor.min.js': ['vendor.js']
            }
        }
    }
});
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your config looks like, but you can easily specify the order of files in grunt-contrib-concat:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    dist: {
      src: ['src/jquery.js', 'src/bootstrap.js'],
      dest: 'dist/built.js'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, the problem is that i'm trying to automate everything so any dependancies are handled automatically, so I do not want to specify the exact files. But this may be the wrong approach.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Either you specify or you don't (which results in alphabetic order). Sounds like RequireJS is what you're looking for, but it has its own downsides.

Comment: Yeah, it was kind of feeling like I was going down a dead end, thank you very much for your help in clarifying the situation.

Comment: If you don't like the overhead of RequireJs, I'd still recommend using AMD, and with a smaller loader, like almond.js. https://github.com/jrburke/almond The benefit of AMD is that you can concat the files whatever way you want and they will still execute in the right order. For smaller projects I would recommend this.

Comment: @MartinHansen. Wanna add an answer based on AMD?